# PHP Tools For Visual Studio HTTP Error 500.0

Tags: php, http, visual-studio-2012, iis-8, internal-server-error

I just started to study php and notepad++ just not doing the job and i wanted to use VS to work with .

So i downloaded PHP tools for Visual Studio , after i write myfile and then try to run it , after i solved couple of problems i got another one i can't handle , here is a pic of it http://i60.tinypic.com/vryqn4.jpg

and it's head title is "IIS 8.0 Detailed error "

So i hope some1 can help me please

Comment: You don't compile PHP. It's a scripting language.

Comment: Well i know that but i may said it by mistake , but this didn't help me , thanks anyway !!

Comment: Well, did you go through "things that you can try"?

Comment: Are you sure your server is able to run PHP?

Comment: PHP Tools will setup everything for you. See https://docs.devsense.com/en/vs especially the section "First PHP Project"